# How to filter query by multiple values with a comma delimited string as source

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have form `frmSelect` that allows a user to choose multiple items from a listbox. The user's selection is then saved on form `frmShowResults`.

The results from the list box, are saved in a textbox control on form `frmShowResults`, as a comma delimited string like this example:

> 1,4,7

I would like to then filter `frmShowResults` based on this selection. I can not use FilterOnLoad, because the forms underlying query has a subquery, with which it does not seem to work. 
This is the SQL of `frmShowResults`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tbl_Activity.ActivityID, tbl_Activity.DepartmentID, tbl_Activity.AStatusID, 
    tbl_Activity.ActivityName, tbl_Activity.Description, tbl_Activity.Archive, 
    tbl_Activity.OpenDate, tbl_Activity.DueDate1, tbl_Activity.DueDate2, 
    tbl_Activity.LastModified, tbl_Activity_Status.Activity_Status, tbl_Department.DepartmentShort
FROM 
    tbl_Department INNER JOIN 
    (tbl_Activity_Status INNER JOIN 
    (tbl_Activity INNER JOIN qry_ReportGenerator3_1 ON 
        (tbl_Activity.ActivityID = qry_ReportGenerator3_1.ActivityID) AND 
        (tbl_Activity.ActivityID = qry_ReportGenerator3_1.ActivityID)) ON 
        tbl_Activity_Status.AStatusID = tbl_Activity.AStatusID) ON 
        tbl_Department.DepartmentID = tbl_Activity.DepartmentID
WHERE (((tbl_Activity.Archive)=False));
```

I have tried setting up formulas in the query design view such as `In ([Forms]![frm_ReportGenerator2]![txtBusAreaWhere])`

Access does not evaluate the statement correctly and returns no records. It does yield the correct number of records however, if I enter it manually as `In (1;4;7)`. *Note: My regional settings dictate that i use semicolons as separators.*

**How can I get my query to filter correctly given my comma delimited string source?**

Comment: Create a table called matches, and put the value from the delimited string into the table.  Then do a join against that table.   I don't use MS-ACCESS, but the other approach (slower), is to used charindex() or indexof, check if the database field is found in the string

Comment: Don't use dynamic parameterized query (I never do). Use VBA to build criteria string and apply to form or report filter.

Comment: @June7 This is what i ended up doing. About parameterized queries: I use them quite a bit and have found them to be an easy solution that works flawlessly on most occasions. Saves on coding and changes can be done quick too. Why don't you like them?

Comment: @Sparky I did not implement your solution with creating a new table. The reason is that if I do that, then the  access front end begins to bloat (file size increases). The charindex suggestion was over my head unfortunately. But I'll look into it when i have time. Cheers!

Comment: Main reason I don't use dynamic parameterized query is it gets tricky to design to allow option of no parameter input by user. And sometimes as developer I want to view query data unfiltered. Also, sometimes dynamic criteria can't be designed into query object - as you encountered with the IN() function. I will often just use an SQL statement as form or report RecordSource instead of building another query object.